# How to change the color of with JInternalFrame Title bar?

Tags: java, swing

I want to change the color of the JInternalFrame Titlebar. I have tried

```
jinternalframe.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(5)`
```

but this will not change the color of title bar it will only create one title bar inside the frame. I want to change the color of title bar with a custom color.

Comment: `UIManager.put("InternalFrame.activeTitleBackground", new ColorUIResource(Color.black ));
UIManager.put("InternalFrame.activeTitleForeground", new ColorUIResource(Color.WHITE))`

Comment: This method won't change the color of the Title bar.

Comment: Not much luck on researching, it seems that perhaps you may need to code a custom solution. Best of luck!

Comment: I do not think it is possible without using your own custom LAF.